# Handling firstname and lastname in passportjs

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, passport.js

i want to know to handle user **firstname** and **lastname** in **passportjs** knowing i tried the folowing code :

```
passport.use('local-register', new passportLocal (strategyOption, function (email, password, firstname, lastname, callback) {
    console.log(' ------- pass :' + password);
            console.log(' ------- email :' + email);
    console.log(' ------- fname :' + firstname);
    console.log(' ------- lname :' + lastname);


    var searchedUser = {
        email: email
    };
    User.findOne(searchedUser, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return callback (err);
        //console.log(user);
        if (user) return callback (null, false, {
           message: 'User do exist!'
        });

        var newUser = new User({
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname,
            email: email,
            password: password
        });
        newUser.save(function (err) {
            if(err) console.log('hi');
            callback (null, newUser);
        });
    });
}));
```

but in the console i got the following stuff :

---- p : pass(the password giving)
---- email : the email ...
---- fname : - here i got a wierd thing -

```
------- fname :function verified(err, user, info) {
if (err) { return self.error(err); }
if (!user) { return self.fail(info); }
self.success(user, info);
```

}
 ------- lname :undefined

and the worst : unknown callback ... so node can't handle the callback and when i delete the fname and the lname parameter .. everything works like a charm so does anyone know how to handle the fname and lname in passport ?

Thankx,

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

Passport config:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new localStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
},
  async (email, password, done) => {
    try {const user = await UserModel.create({
        email, password
      })
      console.log(`Welcome!`)
      return done(null, user);
      }
     catch (error) {
      console.log(`Signup error: ${error}`)
      done(error)
      }
  }));
```

Node js route:

```
router.post(
  '/signup',
  function (req, res, next){ passport.authenticate('local-signup', { session: false }, async function (err, user, info) {
        try {
          await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({email: req.body.email}, { firstName: req.body.firstName, lastName: req.body.lastName }, 
{new: true});

          await req.login(
            user, { session: false },
            (err) => {
              if (err) {
                return next(err);
              }

              const payload = {
     id: user._id, email: user.email
              };
              const token = jwt.sign(
                payload,
                process.env.JWT_TOKEN_SECRET);
              console.log('JWT signed.');
              res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      token: `Bearer ${token}`,
      user: {
        id: user.id,
        email: user.email,
        firstName: user.firstName,
        lastName: user.lastName
      }
    });
            });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('Passport Signup err: ' + err)
          res.send('Sign up error: ' + err)
          return next(err);
        }
      }
    )(req, res, next)
  })
```

In few words, I used "Model.findOneAndUpdate" inside the sign-up route to update the user's document with their first and last names.